Is there a way to have scrollable div the size of its sibling?
I have a page with two divs, the left one is the height of its content. The right one needs to be the same height (so that if I were to scroll the page I can see them both ending at the same point at the bottom) and scrollable because there can be a lot of elements inside of it.
The point at which I am struggling right now is that in order to make this div scrollable it needs to have a height, but at the same time I don't want it to have a set height because it does not reflect the dynamic height of its sibling.
Here is the link with the example https://jsfiddle.net/rq51pchy/5/
The markup is something like this:
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro harum libero ex nostrum, ipsa, cupiditate ipsam mollitia voluptatem expedita modi recusandae suscipit, natus distinctio ratione laudantium nam voluptates quasi iste.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro harum libero ex nostrum, ipsa, cupiditate ipsam mollitia voluptatem expedita modi recusandae suscipit, natus distinctio ratione laudantium nam voluptates quasi iste.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro harum libero ex nostrum, ipsa, cupiditate ipsam mollitia voluptatem expedita modi recusandae suscipit, natus distinctio ratione laudantium nam voluptates quasi iste.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro harum libero ex nostrum, ipsa, cupiditate ipsam mollitia voluptatem expedita modi recusandae suscipit, natus distinctio ratione laudantium nam voluptates quasi iste.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro harum libero ex nostrum, ipsa, cupiditate ipsam mollitia voluptatem expedita modi recusandae suscipit, natus distinctio ratione laudantium nam voluptates quasi iste.</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro harum libero ex nostrum, ipsa, cupiditate ipsam mollitia voluptatem expedita modi recusandae suscipit, natus distinctio ratione laudantium nam voluptates quasi iste.</div>
    <div>Iusto, omnis quibusdam magnam porro odio placeat. Ex molestias consequuntur ad eius nostrum nam, id sunt assumenda! Est expedita sapiente tenetur id, at, doloribus qui maiores placeat error aspernatur soluta!</div>
    <div>Dolor ut, quos consequatur quasi quisquam, blanditiis impedit quidem ducimus voluptas totam itaque suscipit quas. Maxime excepturi fugiat voluptatem tempora sint vero assumenda voluptas ducimus facilis tempore quidem, obcaecati autem?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
     <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
     <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
     <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
     <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
     <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
     <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>the last one</li>
  </div>
</div>

And the styles:
.header {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

li {
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}


Just so I understand, you want the left column to by dynamic and expand to fit the content while the right column matches the left in height but allows scrolling if the content is longer?

Got locked before I could post a solution.  https://jsfiddle.net/b0y3grqv/

@Phaelaxz your solution works great except that when I scroll to the bottom of the right div I don't see some of the bottom items. I can only see them if I scroll again and the whole page scrolls. Not sure if it can be fixed though

@Person if you are ok to define the width of the right container, you can simply add contain:size on your original markup's right container.

For example https://jsfiddle.net/SyndRain/y3htnzaj/1/ Note that you probably want to move the max-height limitation to the left container if you want the max-height:100vh.

@SyndRain yes, it is even better! Thanks. But I have the problem, I scroll to the bottom of the right div and I don't see some of the bottom items. I can only see them if I scroll again and the whole page scrolls.

I'm not sure I follow, I see all the items when I scroll

Well if in the left container  there are more content than the screen can fit, overflow has to happen somewhere. You can limit the left container's max-height to 100vh, or even calc(100vh - 68px), or even an additional vertical flex wrapper if you want

What I meant is that I can scroll in the pink div only to a certain point. If I keep on scrolling (in order to see the last item) this body starts to scroll. And I was wondering if there is a way to make is so I can scroll in the pink div all the way until the last element.

This is contradicting your original requirement. If you want the pink div's height to be limited on screen, it won't be the same height as the left div when the left div is bigger than the screen size. Please edit your question to clarify your requirement. The question is unlikely to be re-opened though unless you explains in your post why the duplicated post doesn't answer your question.

That being said, you can just additionally limit the max-height on the pink div to prevent it grow off-screen.

@SyndRain No, I don't want the height of pink div to be limited to the screen. I guess I am looking for it to behave like the left div here https://codepen.io/johannesjo/pen/AaRdyW

The left div's content is overflowing but its height is same as the screen. If the right div's content is larger than the screen both will overflow.

You can set the same max-height to the .left or to the .parent as is in the .right element.
